# OutputCache serving long-stale data

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, outputcache

I'm flumoxed... re [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87062/whats-wrong-with-rss-feed) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86991/feeds-dont-expire) "meta" questions...

A very basic http request:

```
GET http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=c%23&sort=newest HTTP/1.1
Host: stackoverflow.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
```

which hits a route decorated with:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 300, VaryByParam = "tagnames;sort",
    VaryByContentEncoding = "gzip;deflate", VaryByCustom = "site")]
```

is repeatedly ***and incorrectly*** serving either a 304 (no change) if you include if-modified-since, or *the old data* for a 200, i.e.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Expires: Fri, 01 Jul 2011 09:17:08 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 01 Jul 2011 09:12:08 GMT
Vary: *
Date: Fri, 01 Jul 2011 09:42:46 GMT
Content-Length: 14714
(payload, when decoded = some long-stale data)
```

As you can see, it is serving this nearly half an hour *past* the 5 minute slot; it looks like the internals of OutputCache simply didn't notice the time ;p It will expire *eventually* (in fact, it has just done so - my `Fri, 01 Jul 2011 09:56:20 GMT` request finally got fresh data), but not anywhere like punctually.

UPDATE:

I *believed* that it was working if we took away the accept-encoding header, but no; this fails too - it just fails on a different cycle (which is what we should expect since the keys are different, courtesy of `VaryByContentEncoding`):

```
GET http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=c%23&sort=newest HTTP/1.1
Host: stackoverflow.com
```

gives:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=utf-8
Expires: Fri, 01 Jul 2011 10:09:58 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 01 Jul 2011 10:04:58 GMT
Vary: *
Date: Fri, 01 Jul 2011 10:17:20 GMT
Content-Length: 66815
(payload = some stale data)
```

Once again, you'll notice it is being served *after* `Expires`.

So: what could be wrong here?

Additional; while we are using a custom option, our `GetVaryByCustomString()` correctly calls `base.GetVaryByCustomString(ctx, custom)` for options it doesn't recognise, as per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ecf4420.aspx) (indeed this works fine for the second example above).

Comment: Marc your custom output cache provider wouldn't happen to be open sourced somewhere would it?

Comment: @runxc1 I'd have to check, but our default "go to" tool there is red is via booksleeve (both of which are open source) using some custom wrappers (that are not). However, it sounds wrong in my head to think redis here - I'll have to take a look at the code.

Comment: Did you ever find the custom output cache provider?  Just curious as it feels like the baked in ones are really lacking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is there any chance you're using a custom output cache provider?  *Hypothetically*, if there was a custom provider using say a sliding expiration instead of an absolute one, you'd see symptoms like this.

Comment: Yes; it turns out that ***we suck***

Comment: Jeff **will** fire you for failing to suck a little less today ;))

Comment: Ah well, at least we didn't mess up the time unit; that *would* be embarrassing

Comment: Cache is overrated, your site should be fast enough not to need it.

Comment: @hofnarwillie oh I dunno, I think Stack Overflow is fairing pretty well still :)  Also, he was joking - watch our Channel 9 spot from MIX 2011 to get the reference.